# Why AsyncTask can't implement methods except doInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

In Android Studio, I've  tried to implement the <strike>methods</strike> interface of `AsyncTask`, but it only shows method `doInBackgound()`. I've tried to place the cursor on the AsyncTask and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it only offers method `doInBackgound()`.

[image: screenshot]

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.net.URL;
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's actually an abstract class and not an interface, and only `doInBackground` is abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing only the `AsyncTask::doInBackground(URL...)` is because the method is not implemented in the **abstract class `AsyncTask`**.

However, the others have default implementations and so you can only override them. If you need **IntelliJ** or **Android Studio** to suggest the others, you need to do **CTRL + O**. This will suggest other methods you can override from the parent classes.

Comment: @steve normally when you find an answer helpful you should up vote it and/or accept it as a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl + O for Override methods. See whether OnPostExecute() can be implemented from there.

**Important**: 
OnPostExecute() needs an argument which return from doInBackground(). If the argument is not provided and the method signatures do not match then override annotation may not recognize the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
    }
    }
```